# Why is nav and section overlapping in Bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Why is nav and section overlapping in Bootstrap 5?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" aria-hidden="true" class="mr-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"/><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"/></svg>
        <strong>Album</strong>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>

  <section class="py-5 text-center container">
    <div class="row py-lg-5">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="font-weight-light">Album example</h1>
        <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don’t simply skip over it entirely.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I need to use py to see the hero page correctly.  What is wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Navbar and section will overlap by default you need to add the py-5 which is generally do on main section so that it won't get overlapped. There is nothing wrong with your approach.